# Harvesting a WMS with GeoNetwork

Tags: wms, metadata, geonetwork

I want to harvest from a WMS service like https://nsdiindia.gov.in/nsdi-portal/index.jsp in my geonetwork node and for which I am providing the details as given in the documentation

but I am getting the error like

```
  Unable to add a new entry
  Error : error
   Message : String index out of range: -1
    Class : StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What version of geoNetwork are you using? Can you link to the full log and post the harvesting configuration? Obviously, there is some string on the code that is not on the format geoNetwork is expecting, but without more information we cannot help you.

Comment: The link you give isn't a WMS, so that's probably the cause of your error.